# How to detect mesh collision in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, mesh, mesh-collider

Can we detect mesh collision in unity3d? I want to show some texture on collision, currently I am using box colliders, that's why its surface/edge do not match with the object body mesh, Also even if I get the hit point on the surface of mesh, I don't know how to put a texture on a mesh at specific position over mesh, is there any in-built component specific for the same kind of requirement or a workaround of this in unity3d?

[image]

As we can see in picture the collision has been detected inside the game object because the box collider is inside the target object mesh
**Note: here the actual mesh I have replaced with a dummy cube mesh**

But is there any way to detect when bullet collider/mesh was actually going through the mesh of the target object as in below image I have shown where exactly I want to detect the hit point between target object mesh and bullet mesh/collider also how to draw a texture over here (the hit point on the mesh).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer: No

Because that's not how that works.

### Long answer:

If you want the mesh to be used as the collider, you should set the mesh as the target for a [`MeshCollider` component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html). However, mesh colliders are *very* expensive: Unity needs to recalculate them every time they move, scale, rotate, or otherwise change their boundaries.

There is, however [this asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/super-raycast-91154) which will perform raycasts against the *renderer* mesh, without the need for a collider, but I have no idea what kind of performance hit that will have.